# Can `npm test` run lint only?

Tags: npm, lint

After using `npm test` to do linting, it immediately starts to build all 2000 modules, and since it is already previously built, so I press CTRL-C, but only to find that because it got interrupted in the middle, some files are corrupted.

Is there a way to only run the linting without having it build all the modules?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your lint command is just something user made. If you go into your ***package.json*** and look for the 'test' command, you'll see that it calls several other commands including lint and build. Just make it lint only, or create a seperate function called npm lint. Here's an example package.json. As you can see, it has a lint and a test command.

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start:native": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "start:web": "react-scripts start",
    "lint": "eslint src/**",
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/jest --env=jsdom",
    "test:watch": "node_modules/.bin/jest --verbose --watchAll --env=jsdom"
  }
}
```